# Python IDLE slow to show text I've just typed

Tags: python-idle

I'm new to programming so I'm sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

IDLE can't keep up with my typing, sometimes to the point of me waiting minutes for the line I just typed to appear. I was able to find one reddit thread with my exact issue (linked here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8u8l98/64bit_idle_on_windows_10_is_really_slow_can/) but there was no solution posted. I'm also using Windows 10 if that's relevant.

It happens every time I use it, even after restarting my computer and with it being the only thing running. I tried looking on here to find a similar question, but wasn't able to find an accurate thread. If there's any additional info needed, I am happy to divulge!

Thank you in advance for any replies!

Comment: The problem might be your computer, not the IDLE

Comment: @kiki7000 Thank you for replying! If you don't mind explaining, how would I know if that is the case?

Comment: The reason I thought that is because, on my computer, typing speed was regular

Comment: @kiki7000 That makes sense! All of the people I've asked before have never had this issue or heard of it, so you're probably right.

Comment: Keystrokes (and mouse actions) are first handled by the OS.  It generates events and sends them to the GUI window manager.  For IDLE and tkinter, that is tcl/tk and its Text widget.  Really long lines (1000s of chars) bog down Text.  100000s of normal lines do not.  This is probably not your issue, but I don't know what else could be. (What version of Python?)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thank you for the insight on how it all works! I'm using Python 3.9.0 as I downloaded it just a week or two ago. Something I just noticed is that Python itself has no delay whatsoever, only IDLE. I'm not sure if that is relevant or not!

Comment: The link says Windows 10.  Are you using that as well?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes! I am also using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a test program.

```
import tkinter as tk
r = tk.Tk()
t = tk.Text(r)
t.pack()
r.mainloop()
```

Run this directly in Python, without IDLE, or run it in IDLE, possibly without the last line.  Stretch the tk window to a reasonable size.  Click on the blank area and try typing.

Comment: When I run it directly in Python, everything works as I imagine it should! There is no delay in typing. 

When I run it in IDLE (was able to include the last line with no issue), the delay is still there albeit a little less severe. Around 10 seconds instead of 30+. 

Thank you so much for helping me out with this! I hope this information can shed a little light on what's going on.